# Как найти одинаковую подстроку в массиве строк?

Tags: c#

Имеется массив строк:

```
[
    "D:\\src\\files\\folder/5.3.231/file.exe",
    "D:\\src\\files\\folder/5.1.1/file.exe",
    "D:\\src\\files\\folder/4.1/sub/file55.exe"
]
```

Нужно найти подстроку, которая бы была частью каждой строки массива с позиции 0 (с самого начала).

Comment: Есть еще проще все: [ссылка на сайтик](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getparent?view=net-7.0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это задача называется `Longest common prefix`, решить её можно следующим образом:

```
public string LongestCommonPrefix(string[] strs)
{
    if (strs == null || strs.Length == 0)
        return "";

    return CommonPrefix(strs, 0, strs.Length - 1);
}

private string CommonPrefix(string[] strs, int start, int end)
{
    if (start == end)
        return strs[start];

    int middle = (start + end) / 2;

    var left = CommonPrefix(strs, start, middle);
    var right = CommonPrefix(strs, middle + 1, end);
    return ConquerString(left, right);
}

private string ConquerString(string left, string right)
{
    int currentSmallest = Math.Min(left.Length, right.Length);
    for (int i = 0; i < currentSmallest; i++)
    {
        if (left[i] != right[i])
            return left.Substring(0, i);
    }
    return left.Substring(0, currentSmallest);
}
```

Разбор этой задачи с построением дерева вызовов можете найти на просторах ютуба, алгоритм довольно простой если его визуализировать. Работает алгоритм только если гарантированно у всех элементов массива есть одинаковый префикс

Comment: Фактически же двоичным поиском ищется элемент до которого строки одинаковые от начала? )

Answer (score 0):

Благодаря названию задачи от @Kalmankantaja нашёл более изящный вариант на просторах интернета:

```
var commonPrefix = new string(
    samples.First().Substring(0, samples.Min(s => s.Length))
    .TakeWhile((c, i) => samples.All(s => s[i] == c)).ToArray());
```